# Emulate the second parameter of setState in a useState environment. Let something happen after setState has occured

Tags: reactjs, state, react-hooks

Well in previous react version we could execute code after the state has changed by doing something like:

```
setState( prevState => {myval: !prevState.myval}, () => {
    console.log("myval is changed now");
)
```

And make sure the second "bit" is only executed with the updated code. Now one of the examples describes something "similar" can be achieved using `React.useEffect`:

```
const [myval, setMyval] = React.useState(false);
React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("myval is changed now");
}

//somewhere
setMyval(o => !o);
```

While this looks fine and dandy, it doesn't help in my case: in my case "what effect needs to happen" depends on the location where the state has changed, originally:

```
//somewhere
setState( prevState => {myval: !prevState.myval}, () => {
    console.log("myval is changed now");
)
//somewhere else 
setState( prevState => {myval: !prevState.myval}, () => {
    console.log("myval has changed somewhere else");
)
```

Changing these to `useState` + `setMyval` would let the same effect fire at both positions, so we cannot derive in useEffect what action actually needs to occur.

How would I do above in a hook based function component?

---

A better usecase would be a screen which has two buttons, one to load previous, another to load next. The buttons are disabled while `isLoading` state is true and only perform actions when loading. To make sure only a single load can happen we cannot just "act" as if state changes immediately: state changing is asynchronous and thus a race condition might occur.

Using a callback upon changing state prevents this race condition and makes sure only a single load happens:

```
class SomScreen extends React.component {
    state = { isLoading: false }
    render() {
        <div>
            <button 
                disabled={this.state.isLoading} 
                onclick={(e) => {
                    if (!this.state.isLoading) {
                            this.setState((p) => ({isLoading: true}), () => {
                            await fetchPreviousDataAndDoSomethingWithIt()
                            setState({isLoading: false});
                        });
                    }
                }
            />Previous</button>
            <button 
                disabled={this.state.isLoading} 
                onclick={(e) => {
                    if (!this.state.isLoading) {
                        this.setState((p) => ({isLoading: true}), () => {
                            await fetchNextDataAndDoSomethingWithIt()
                            setState({isLoading: false});
                        });
                    }
                }
            />Next</button>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question "is an async action in flight" is a reduce across "are any of these async actions in flight", so you could model each async action separately and then compute `isLoading`. A custom hook like this might work:

```js
function useAsyncAction(asyncAction) {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const callAsyncAction = useCallback(async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    await asyncAction();
    setIsLoading(false);
  }, []);
  return [
    isLoading,
    callAsyncAction,
  ]
}

//

function SomScreen() {
  const [asyncAIsLoading, callAsyncA] =
    useAsyncAction(fetchPreviousDataAndDoSomethingWithIt);
  const [asyncBIsLoading, callAsyncB] =
    useAsyncAction(fetchNextDataAndDoSomethingWithIt);
  const isLoading = asyncAIsLoading || asyncBIsLoading

  ...
}
```

Comment: While this would work initially, the further problem - prevent the action from happening if `isLoading` is true wouldn't work right? - As each asyncAction would have to look into each other action, or conversely, the "more global" `isLoading` would only be set next rerender. I guess I could use it as one doesn't expect multiple user inputs within a single frame, but it doesn't seem correct.

Comment: `<button disabled={isLoading}>` could be used as many times as you like to disable buttons.

Comment: If you're looking for a guarantee on rendering, even `setState` doesn't provide a guarantee as to when *exactly* a component will re-render after a `setState` call.